# How to Delete a single subcollection from the firestore database collection?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to delete a single image from a list of images. Currently, it is deleting the postImg field totally, However, I am trying to delete a single image from the list,
Here is my try,

```
const handleDelete = async postId => {
    const deleteImg = await firestore()
      .collection(`${user.email}`)
      .doc(postId)
      .update({
        postImg: firestore.FieldValue.delete(),
      });
    console.log(deleteImg);
  };
```

Here **id = 'FcXwUNg92k9i21LAWGZo'**

```
<Icon
  name="trash-outline"
  size={28}
  color="white"
  onPress={() => handleDelete(id)}
/>
```

Here is my database,
[image: Firestore Database]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `postImg` field contains an array, so you need to remove the specific element from array list.
To remove from an array in firestore use `arrayRemove()`

```
const reference = db.collection(user.email).doc(postId);    
reference.update({
    postImg: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove(<full_image_path_to_remove>)
});
```